# Golang ListenAndServeTLS returns data when not using https in the browser

Tags: http, ssl, https, go

The following is my tls backend:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    PORT       = ":8443"
    PRIV_KEY   = "./private_key"
    PUBLIC_KEY = "./public_key"
)

func rootHander(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Nobody should read this.")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHander)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(PORT, PUBLIC_KEY, PRIV_KEY, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("main(): %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

The keys are generated using these two lines:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key private_key -out public_key -days 365
```

When I start the tls server, and visit the site with a browser (https://example.com:8443) I get the expected result, *after* ignoring the browser warning:

```
Nobody should read this.
```

So far everything is cool.

Now, when I point my browser to http://example.com:8443 (notice that http is used, *not* https) I get the following result for Firfox (Chrome does the same, but downloading the site):

[image: using http]

**Question**: Why is there a question mark?

Comment: Does https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ZtP5vPPeyHE work for you too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pipe the output into od, `curl -k -3 http://localhost:8443 | od -A n -t x1`, you get the following sequence of bytes `15  03  01  00  02  02  0a` which is rendered/handled by the browser.

Which, according to https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2253, is TLS for "I didn't understand what you said."

Comment: So, it's by design. If I want allow only https, I should redirect, right?

Comment: @Kiril Is there already any solution for this issue? What do you mean by "redirect"?

Comment: This is actually expected behaviour. You can check https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request (TLS) to know whether a request is using http or https.

Comment: Is there any way to force the browser to use https ? As there is only one port on which the server listens, being 8443, if accessed via http then user should be redirected.

Comment: No way to force the browser. Redirect happens in HTTP, HTTP is encapsulated by TLS.

Answer (score 4):

If at all still relevent:

`http.ListenAndServeTLS(...)` takes *certificate* and *private key* not *public* & *private key*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I created a certificate with a corresponding private key?

Comment: Yes. You created a certificate with a private key. You just named the cert "public_key". Usually it is done more like this: `-out cert.pem`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to redirect requests on port 80 to 443 and to serve up tls certificates using a CA like lets encrypt. I know that with lets encrypt ([letsencrypt.org](http://letsencrypt.org)) you want to reference the resulting fullchain.pem file as well as the privkey.pem.

The biggest problem with self signing is that it wont be very viable in production. With golang we really configure our applications quite specifically so something simple like attaching tls certs properly is an important topic when we are ready to launch.

here some simple code I have actually used to launch a static site:

```
package main
import (
"net/http"
"log"
)
func redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
 // remove/add not default ports from req.Host
 target := "https://" + req.Host + req.URL.Path
 if len(req.URL.RawQuery) > 0 {
     target += "?" + req.URL.RawQuery
 }
 log.Printf("redirect to: %s", target)
 http.Redirect(w, req, target,
         http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
 }


func main() {
 //define a variable for the FileServer directory in this case ./static/
 var fs = http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
 //express the handler function
 http.Handle("/", fs)
 //We should redirect requests on port 80
 go http.ListenAndServe(":80", http.HandlerFunc(redirect))
 //finally we Listen for requests and serve them up on a specific port
 http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "fullchain.pem", "privkey.pem", nil)

 }
```